# Post image lacking when pasting link into Facebook despite the correct og:image meta tag

Tags: facebook, social-sharing

Within `head` tags of [this post page](http://goo.gl/lcEugU) (sorry there's a language selection prompt screen), Yoast SEO Plugin generates this:

```
<meta content="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/whatever.jpg" property="og:image">
```

Although the image linked here is Facebook compliant (above 200x200px), there's still no image appearing when pasting the post link into Facebook. Why?

Comment: I have posted the solution for you. As a side note, I noticed you've posted over 100 questions with no answers. I suggest that you use the valuable knowledge you have gained by contributing with answers too =)

Comment: Thx Christine, I upvoted your answer but can't accept it as my problem remains unresolved. I'll try to follow your advice about answering questions though!

Answer (score 4):

Facebook caches the meta values for performance. So it is currently hosting an old version of the shared URL. You need to use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), and **Fetch new scrap info.**

This will update the stored meta values of the post.

To confirm that it works, I have already fetched new data for the respective URL and this is how it looks when I share it on FB:

[image]

Additionally, I should highlight that Facebook normally stores shared data in your FB user account as well. So in order for you to see the updated share, try with a different account. This is not always the case but I have seen this behaviour before so it's worth mentioning regardless.

Comment: Thanks Christine, but this seems to work only on a post basis. Using the FB debugger I can make it work for one post in particular, but the next post I'm trying to share doesn't work. I would have to do this for all posts and that's not really an option in my case... Any suggestion to make it work for the whole website?

Comment: Sure, are you using any caching plugins? If so, clear the cache completely.

Comment: I have no caching plugin of any kind running of this site I'm afraid...

Comment: As a temporary hack you could try adding a query var to yoast's ouput using its filter: `add_filter( 'wpseo_og_og_image', function ( $content ) { return $content . '?scrape=true'; } );` which according to a comment on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10289336/664741 _may_ cause FB to re-cache...please note _may_...!

Comment: Great stuff @bonger! As a side-note, the only posts you should refresh are the ones that were shared on FB prior to you adding the yoast. Which I doubt are that many. Additionally, FB does indeed clear their stored data automatically after a set interval. I don't know what it's set to but I am sure about this as I have seen this behavior very often myself.

Comment: @bonger: works but only after pasting an URL into FB for the third or fourth time (and after that it works every time). So if I pick an URL I've never shared before, paste it into FB, image doesn't appear. I refresh FB, paste it again, still doesn't work. But on third or fourth time it works. Would you know why and how to get it work on first time?

Comment: I don't, no I'm afraid - to be honest I avoid doing anything with FB like the plague, mickey mouse api - not that that helps you! Perhaps try stackoverflow...